# 100% without breaking to new line

Tags: html, width

I need to put input with width: 100%; in one line with text(more precisely one character):

```
+<input style="width: 100%;" type="tel />
```

Comment: Awesome, what have you tried?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha only float :) It seems simple but I have no idea(decrease width isn't what I want)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if the input is 100% wide nothing else can be on that line

Is this somewhat what you want?

http://jsfiddle.net/NVzfs/3/

Comment: so isn't possible to make input use all free space without breaking to new line?(without making width less than 100%)

Comment: Using `width: 1em;` would probably make more sense, but still, well done.

Comment: can you make an example please :)